# Eclipse wont generate R.java for achartengine.org

Tags: android, eclipse, achartengine

I have downloaded achartengine and imported him.
But when i import it Eclipse wont generate the R.java file.
I look into to source code they give to download and there is no R.java file.
I know to Eclipse should make it by itself by mine dont.

I tried clean.

build automatically is checked.

remove/import the package.

restart eclipse.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: if R.java is not generated automatically, likely you have error in your resources files check the resource for errors.

Comment: did u build(i.e add to build path) achartengine ...and who is "him"

Comment: check i you have added achartengine-1.0.0(version).jar to your libs folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the project will not generate R file if you have errors in your xml files under res folder.Check your all the res xml files and correct the errors and clean the project it will generate the R file for sure.And also check other resources like drawables. may be you are having drawables with invalid names.